# Is this the correct way to calculate lat/lon in all directions (NSEW)?

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I've tested this in google maps, and it seems legit. But I'm not quite sure I understand the formula correctly. Does East and West need to be `* 180` instead of `* 90` ?

```
EARTH_RAD = 6378
...
def calculate_distance(lat, lon, direction)
  case direction
  when :north
    lat = (@kilometers/(EARTH_RAD * (Math::PI/2))) * 90 + lat
    [lat, lon]
  when :south
    lat = (lat - (@kilometers/(EARTH_RAD * (Math::PI/2))) * 90)
    [lat, lon]
  when :east
    lon = (@kilometers/(EARTH_RAD * (Math::PI/2))) * 90 + lon
    [lat, lon]
  when :west
    lon = (lon - (@kilometers/(EARTH_RAD * (Math::PI/2))) * 90)
    [lat, lon]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula for meridians (NS) is right, but for parallels is wrong. It is because meridian length is near constant (~40000 km), but parallel length (and km/degree ratio) depends on latitude. 111 km east is equal to 1 degree at equator, and to 1.41 degrees at 45 latitude parallel.

So you have to account for coefficient `Cos(lat)` like this (don't know ruby syntax for cos function)

```
lon = (@kilometers/(Math::Cos(lat_in_radians) * EARTH_RAD * (Math::PI/2))) * 90 + lon
```

Don't forget about transit through date change line (180 degrees) for EW, and through equator for NS.

note that `90 / (Math::PI/2)` is coefficient to translate radians to degrees